# In Meteor, the old way to define a helper function is not conflict to the new way?

Tags: javascript, meteor, helper

I am new to Meteor and tried to follow the "Your First Meteor Application":
http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/
I tried to define a helper function.
In the html file I wrote:

```
<head>
    <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
    {{> leaderboard}}
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
    <!-- Hello World -->
    <!-- {{player}} -->
    <!-- {{otherHelperFunction}} -->
<ul>
    {{#each player}}
        <li>{{name}}:{{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul> 

{{numOfPlayer}}
</template>
```

And in the JS file I wrote:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
        "player": function(){
            // return "Some other text";
            return PlayersList.find();
        },
        "numOfPlayer": function(){
            // return "Some other text";
            return PlayersList.find().count();
        },
        "otherHelperFunction": function(){
            return "Some other funciton";
        }
    })
    Template.leaderboard.player = function(){
    return "Some other text";
    }
    // console.log("Hello client");

}

if(Meteor.isServer){
    console.log("Hello server");
}

PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

So here in the JS file for the client part, I defined two "player" helper functions: one in the old way and one in the new way. The old way is actually that I forgot to comment out but when I run this project, the website turned out to be executed in the "new way" and seemed that the old-way defined "player" helper function did not influence the project at all and the compiler did not say that there is any error or ambiguity (since you can see these two "player" helper function are defined for different functionalities). What is the reason for this? Is it because that the old-way defined helper function is overwritten by the new helper function?

This is the output interface.
[image: Here is the output interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Meteor source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#name-resolution):

> The first identifier in a path is resolved in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Indexing the current data context. The identifier foo refers to the foo property of the current data context object.
> 2. As a template helper. The identifier foo refers to a helper function (or constant value) that is accessible from the current template.
>
> Template helpers take priority over properties of the data context.

Your Template.leaderboard.player function definition is on the data context, therefore Blaze looks for a template helper first. Since you have the helper defined, it takes precedence and gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the new way overrides the old way. New way assigns a new function reference the variable 'player'.